# CosmosDB: MongoDB API How to fix duplicate element names

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I have a .net Core 3.1 application. We're using CosmosDB 3.2 but after migrating to 3.6 we ended up having this duplicate key.
Note: The image is just representative to how the issue looks like.

[image]

Comment: Hi Melchia, can you share the code you are using to update the database? It's hard to repro the issue without it.

Comment: Can you share your sample code without sensitive info ?